# Употребление деепричастия "брав"

Tags: грамотная-речь, деепричастия

Как необходимо исправить предложение?

**— Сейчас, не брав в руки книжку, можно все узнать с помощью компьютера.**

Существует ли вообще такая форма — **брав**?

Answer (score 1):

В современном русском языке деепричастия на "-в" от бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида считаются формами архаичными, хотя иногда и встречающимися.

Поэтому **"беря"** или в подчеркнуто стилизованной форме "бравши". И на мой вкус лучше в конец фразы. Почему - не могу объяснить, хотя подозреваю, что не так естественнее для деепричастного оборота в безличном предложении.
***Сейчас можно все узнать с помощью компьютера, не беря в руки книжку***

По поводу примера  "Не брав никогда взяток, он заработал репутацию честного полицейского". В любом случае деепричастный оборот тут режет слух, поскольку тут по смыслу постоянное, повторяющееся дейcтвие. Тут, думаю, надо заменить деепричастный оборот причастным:

***Не бравший никогда взяток, он заработал репутацию честного полицейского***. Смысл сразу проясняется. Семантика, кстати, не сильно поменяется, поскольку такое приложение несет явный оттенок обстоятельственного значения.

*) ответ существенно переработан, первая версия была совершенно сырая.

Answer (score 0):

Такая форма существует: это деепричастие прошедшего времени от глагола "брать", например:

> Не брав никогда взяток, он заработал репутацию честного полицейского.

Однако в примере из вопроса признак *прошедшего* времени не сочетается с общим смыслом высказывания: предполагаемое действие относится к *настоящему* ("сейчас") и потенциально к будущему - как будто *сейчас можно что-то сделать, в прошлом не делав чего-то другого*. Правильнее здесь было бы "**не беря**".

Comment: У деепричастий по современной грамматике категорию грамматического времени обычно не выделяют. Только вид - совершенный/несовершенный. Не знаю, откуда ваш пример, но уверен, что из позапрошлого века. Хотя и тогда скорее сказали бы "бравши", "брав" - это норма вообще для века XVIII.

Comment: Пример из современной книжки: _Не знаю почему, **никогда не брав** видеокамеру на закрытие Башни, в этот день я её взял._ (В. Махотин: спасибо, до свидания! Абакумова С., Головин В., Издание второе, дополненное). Деепричастие "штучное", но употребляется и сейчас (архаично было бы "бравши"). Вопрос был не о классах деепричастий, поэтому "прошедшее время" здесь лишь наследуется от исходного глагола: это смысловой признак, а не классификационный термин при деепричастии.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве варианта: **Сейчас, даже не беря в руки книжку, можно все узнать с помощью компьютера.**

Вместо усилительной частицы И использована усилительная частица ДАЖЕ,

**Виды и формы причастий**

Деепричастия бывают **двух видов:** совершенного вида и несовершенного вида. В первом случае они обозначают действие, одновременное  с глаголом-сказуемым, во втором случае действие обычно предшествует действию глагола-сказуемого.

От глагола ***брать*** (несов. вид) образуется деепричастие несов. вида ***беря*** (основная форма с суффиксом А/Я, 75 примеров в Нацкорпусе)  и деепричастие несов. вида  **бравши** (разговорная форма с суффиксом ВШИ, 4 примера в Нацкорпусе,).

Суффикс В обычно используется для образования деепричастий совершенного вида: избрать ― избрав, но в старых книгах   форма ***брав*** применялась (6 примеров в Нацкорпусе).

**Примеры:**

Нет совсем, нет на этом свете, а ведь он всю жизнь защищал мужиков, **не беря** ни копейки принципиально. [Борис Васильев. Дом, который построил Дед (1990-2000)]

Высокопар хулит Трутня, **не бравши** в руки ни одного листа. [Н. И. Новиков. Трутень. Еженедельное издание на 1769 год месяц май (1769)].

Можно быть им, никогда **не брав** в руки карт. [Н. Э. Гейнце. Князь Тавриды (1898)]

Answer (score 0):

*Существует ли вообще такая форма — **брав**?*
Да, существует, вернее, существовала и использовалась ранее.

Посмотрите, вот эта форма деепричастия в [**словаре Даля**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=nVBoCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA1040&lpg=PA1040&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=WjeHR7eVkE&sig=UD2fnCl7H13K1pjwm9Fc2YxaYrE&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB6rX8u6PaAhXLDywKHSwaAVEQ6AEITjAG#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE&f=false) (**1863-1866**):
*Взаймы **не брав**, хоть гол, да прав.*

Вот у В. Н. Татищева ([**История Российская. Часть 2.**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=npNCymM9np8C&pg=RA5-PT239&lpg=RA5-PT239&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=hKksLGTvcl&sig=Uv3F2L4O0lXTMuIp0IW1GRZ8M0s&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqzrXo36PaAhVOzaQKHetLBqs4ChDoAQgoMAE#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE&f=false) **1773**):
*А сыновья Святослава со Владимиром объехали половцев и всех их порубили, **не брав** в плен никого, разве знатнейших...*

У Л. Д. Шаховской ([**Сивилла – волшебница Кумского грота.**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=WxZJDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT9&lpg=PT9&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D1%83%20%D0%AE%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=8B1I1nVUAX&sig=8iDVZr2r_VF9m6G0VnDx123jarI&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp7NKw2aHaAhVLKFAKHc1zBXAQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D1%83%20%D0%AE%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0&f=false) **1882**):
***Не брав*** ни у кого уроков, Ютурна по слуху выучилась играть на лире и свирели от детей.

В настоящее время правильным считается использование деепричастия **беря́** (что делая?) от глагола **брать** (что делать?). Именно эта форма закреплена у [**А. А. Зализняка**](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-paradigm-term-5850.htm).

Ваше предложение я бы написала так:
*Сейчас, **даже не беря** в руки книжку, можно все узнать с помощью компьютера.*